# Bootstrap Tooltips are not disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Fullcalendar control and I defined tooltips for its items. I often get the situation when items are removed/moved, but tooltips still exist.

I could workaround this by using `$('.tooltip').hide();` for button click. 
Is there any possibility to hide all existing tooltips before creating a new one?

```
 eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.tooltip({
                html: true,
                container: 'body',
                title: function() {

                    return generateTooltipForFlight(event).html();
                }
            });

           },
```

[image: Tooltips]

Comment: Please post your JS code where you create the tooltips.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, please see my update in the post

Answer (score 0):

What if you use this code:

For JS

```
 $('body').tooltip({
        selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
 });
```

For an element-html

```
  <i class="icon-info-sign" rel="tooltip" 
   title="here you can add the message for the tooltip"></i>
```

This code helped me a lot. I hope it may help you,too.